# Active page Dropdown Menu Hover not working

Tags: drop-down-menu, hover, current-page

I am creating a website using wordpress/elementor. I changed the colors for the main menu in Customize. They work fine but not for the active page, where the hovering doesn't work. I am not familiar with css or coding, I would like to know whether anyone of you could help me solve this issue. The link to my website is [www.serraluisa.com](http://www.serraluisa.com)

Thanks!!

I  would like the active page dropdown menu to behave like the other dropdown menu.